# problems using cron to run a pymongo script

Tags: python, mongodb, cron, pymongo

I'm running a simple python script sending data to a mongodb

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime
import pymongo
from pymongo import Connection

today = { 'date and time' : datetime.today() }

connection = Connection()
db = connection.tests
collection = db.times

collection.insert(today)
```

And I'm trying to use cron to schedule this every minute. I've used crontab to set this

```
* * * * * /Users/MyUser/XX/YY/ZZ/timetest.py
```

And I can execute this perfectly using `python timetest.py` from the correct directory; however the program is still not running on its own. I feel like I'm very close to getting it to work, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does running /Users/MyUser/XX/YY/ZZ/timetest.py at the shell prompt work?

Comment: No this does not work. The output is 'command not found'.

Comment: Have you tried with `python /Users/MyUser/XX/YY/ZZ/timetest.py`?

Comment: that did it. thank you so much. i didn't realize you could put the call for python before the path in the crontab.

Comment: GIven your 2 comments - I suspect you need to make the script executable what does ls -l /Users/MyUser/XX/YY/ZZ/timetest.py

Comment: You're right. I hadn't made my script executable. I just made it executable via "chmod +x timetest.py" so now when I call "ls -l" it reads "-rwxr-xr-x  1 MyUser  staff  268 Sep 22 22:03 timetest.py". However, I'm having difficulties with crontab still. Now it's not working even when I call python before the path in crontab. Is it more efficient to make the script executable than having to call python? When I was running crontab with the python call my harddrive was running constantly, even though the scripts were every other hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the cron environment does not match your user's environment. In cron you can either set the path variable in crontab like

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
* * * * * /Users/MyUser/XX/YY/ZZ/timetest.py
```

or you can just explicitly call the python binary on your script

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /Users/MyUser/XX/YY/ZZ/timetest.py
```

or you can set the shebang line in your script to reference the python binary explicitly (this may not be desirable if you ever use virtualenv)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
...
```